Size of EditableGraph
In NetGraph's EditableGraph, the drawing figure appears to be enclosed in a square. How can we extend the drawing limit of the figure along the horizontal-axis? Thank you.

As with every matplotlib figure, you can change the axis limits in various ways:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import EditableGraph

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = EditableGraph(..., ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 3)


the EditableGraph area is still embedded in a square and do not cover all the window witdh.
